# Adding random numbers into a linked-list using loop

Tags: c++, random, linked-list

I want to add a completely random number into a linked-list, but instead of having all of my code in main, I want to use the object-oriented approach. I have my standard Node class and it's header, and then in main I want a loop that runs through 20 times and then stops adding more. I was given my insert function and how it would be called in main, but I can't seem to get the random numbers to work. I understand that you can't assign an int to a class, but I don't really know how else to incorporate my random number into my function in order to insert it into my list.

Here is my code. Observe the error on line 20 of main. Any insight would be great. Thanks!

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    Node link_head;
    Node instance;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int random = rand() % 100;

        instance.insert(&link_head, &random);
    }
}
```

Node.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

typedef int ElementType;

class Node
{
public:

    Node();
    ElementType data;
    Node *next;
    int insert(Node *, Node *);

};

#endif NODE_H
```

Node.cpp

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

Node::Node()
{
    this -> data = 0;
    this -> next = NULL;
}

int Node::insert(Node *link_head, Node *newNode)
{
        Node *current = link_head;

        while (true) 
        { 
            if(current->next == NULL)
            {
                current->next = newNode;
                break;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the address of an int to a function requiring a pointer on a Node. Allocate a new node first then send it to the function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int random = rand() % 100;

    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = random;
    instance.insert(&linkHead, newNode);
}
```

As stated, insert method should really be static of even a free function since it access only public members of the struct.

Comment: Thank you. I was too busy worrying about the error to focus on the logic of my code. It was a super easy fix. Darn coding.

Comment: @AustinAllenJulio Have a look at my answer, may be this enlightens you a bit more ...

Comment: Hum why the downvote, at least comment so I can improve the answer.

Comment: _'Hum why the downvote'_ `instance.insert(&linkHead, newNode);` will fix the compiler error, but not the flawed concept.

Comment: While I agree, the question is not about that topic and for what it's worth, the method is not static(and he stated that the insert method was given to him) so I wouldn't downvote an answer for that. Cheers.

Comment: @EricFortin Yes, OP's tend to ask the wrong questions about their code ;) ... My experience is that this kind of answer generates follow up questions or comments (even if accepted) like: _But now I have the following problem, blah blah ..._

Comment: Downvote their question then ;) But like I said, insert function was given to him and it is not static so what can I do ...

Comment: @EricFortin Hmmm, no. The question is valid, shows the relevant code, and mentions the (primary) problem, a.s.o. If you really care about your 2pts rep, I'll release my downvote (if you at least hint the OP about their other flaws, or upvote my answer alternatively ;D ).

Comment: It's not about the point, it's about the fact that my answer is not wrong but if you really want you 10 points. I am good with that.

Comment: @EricFortin Yes sometimes I just want my ten points, and how it is now it should really help the OP, or other researchers landing here ;) ...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is flawed in several ways.

1. `instance.insert(&link_head, &random);` `&random` doesn't point to a `Node`, thus the compiler error
2. `int insert(Node *, Node *);` should be `static int insert(Node **, Node *);` and used as follows

---

```
Node* head = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = rand() % 100;
    Node::insert(&head, newNode);
}
```

Where the implementation looks like:

```
int Node::insert(Node** link_head, Node *newNode)
{
    if(!link_head) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(!(*link_head)) {
        *link_head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        newNode->next = (*link_head)->next;
        (*link_head)->next = new_node;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The difference is you use a `head` reference as an *anchor* for the linked list and you'll not have a useless instance that always needs to be sorted out from the actual values stored in the list.